# how to make metadata private?

Tags: private-blockchain

I'd like to create customized NFT including metadata which is readable by only permitted users such as an owner. Is it possible to build? If yes, please let me know how to build it. Should I need to build new token protocol instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any data in the blockchain is public. So, no, your scenario is not possible.

Even if you use contract visibility settings such as `private` it only means that the data can't be used by other contracts but humans outside the blockchain can still get that data.